# Derivation of centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, differentiation, centripetal-force

While reading HC Verma chapter 7 circular motion I came across a derivation which I couldnt understand. I have marked my doubt with red. I don't understand from where  +dw/dt [- i sine +j cos0] came from.

[image: I was unable to understand what happened at the stage marked red]

Comment: $\left[ -\vec{i} \sin\theta + \vec{j} \cos\theta \right]$ is a unit vector (check its size), so ask yourself "Which way does it point?"

Comment: derivative for multiplication, from equation (ii): d(xy)/dt=x dy/dt+y dx/dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the product rule of derivatives, that states d(f*g(t))/dt=f(t)*(dg/dt)+g(t)*(df/dt). In this case, let's call this part: (-i*sinθ+jcosθ)=g(t), and solve it: d(rωg)/dt=r(dωg/dt)=r(ω*(dg/dt)+g(dω/dt)). If you substitute g for (-i*sinθ+jcosθ), you get the equation for acceleration your book presents.